# Anchor element messes up HTML in HAML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

For some reason this HAML code here

```
.text
  %h3= h user.username
  %a.account= "just a test"
```

translates to:

```
<div class="text">
  <a href="http://myapp:3000/user12">
    <h3>dijkstra</h3>
  </a>
  <a>just a test</a>
</div>
```

Clearly I didn't want the anchor tag to fetch some random other anchor tag with a URL I haven't entered and wrap the `h3` element. How can I fix this?

Comment: wht is that h in `%h3= h user.username`

Comment: @Sontya, the syntax is of Haml, %h for html h tag, and = is for writing ruby code onward. You can learn Haml from here - https://github.com/haml/haml

Comment: @SharvyAhmed - I already coded in Haml, I know that. %h3 is h3 in html, that's why I posted corrected code in my answer. I was asking about the extra h you can see in line above

Comment: @Sontya, sorry I got you wrong, my bad! Please don't be offended. :)

Comment: @Sontya I think is the shortcut for the `html_escape` helper (but `user.username` should be escaped by default, so probably is redundant)

Comment: @SharvyAhmed - no problem dude, I am here too learn and help.

Comment: That Haml won’t produce the HTML you claim it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use view helper method `link_to`, I assume that you are using Rails

```
.text
  %h3= user.username
  = link_to 'Just a test', root_url, class: 'account'
```

You can get the complete reference [**here**](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.text
    %h3= user.username
    just a test
```

Comment: But I need the anchor element for CSS reasons

Comment: which anchor element?